# Regex to match string 2 times but not 3

Tags: c#, regex

I try to regex match string like these examples:

> NetTAP IPX C-4-16
>
> SmartTAP DP6409 Dual E1-11-16

but not these ones:

> NetTAP IPX C-4-16-0
>
> SmartTAP DP6409 Dual E1-11-16-0
>
> SYSTEM

I've tried some solutions without success.

My idea was to search the -\d\d 2 times but not 3 times

```regex
(?!\-\d+)(\-\d+){2}$
```

or

```regex
[^(\-\d+)](\-\d+){2}$
```

Could you help me?

Comment: You're using `negative look ahead`. You should use `negative look back`:  `(?<!\-\d+)(\-\d+){2}$`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use

```
(?<!-\d+)(?:-\d+){2}$
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/xQTs3V/1). *Details*:

- `(?<!-\d+)` - a negative lookbehind that fails the match if there is a `-` char and one or more digits immediately to the left of the current location
- `(?:-\d+){2}` - two repetitions of `-` and one or more digits
- `$` - end of string.

Comment: just a question: doesn't minus symbol need "\" ?

Comment: @oliviersow No, `-` is only special inside character classes, i.e. inside unescaped square brackets.

Answer (score 0):

You can also match 3 times what you want to avoid, and capture 2 times what you want to keep using a capture group.

```
(?:-\d+){3}$|(-\d+-\d+)$
```

The pattern matches:

- `(?:-\d+){3}$` Match 3 repetitions at the end of the string
- `|` Or
- `(-\d+-\d+)$` capture 2 repetitions at the end of the string in group 1

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/bA8J2W/1)

Comment: sorry but your answer doesn't work because it matches unwanted string too
> NetTAP IPX C-4-16-0
> SmartTAP DP6409 Dual E1-11-16-0

Comment: @oliviersow You have to get the group 1 value from the match.